# LSM6DSOX IMU sensor: interrupts necessary?

Tags: interrupts, imu, gpio-external-interrupt

I have a question about the interrupt pin of the [LSM6DSOX](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2736724.pdf) IMU.

Can the interrupt pin be used to send an interrupt signal to my microcontroller to notify me when the sensor is detecting a change in velocity or tilt?

Do I need to rely on interrupts, or can I also just read the current acceleration and tilt every few milliseconds via its SPI interface?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the datasheet, the LSM6DSOX can be programmed to generate interrupts when selected events are detected.

These can be complex events: *"implementing hardware recognition of free-fall events, 6D orientation, click and double-click sensing, activity or inactivity, stationary/motion detection and wakeup events"*.

You can read the current acceleration and tilt through the SPI registers while the interrupts are enabled. The interrupts save an SPI bus master from having to read registers and poll the LSM6DSOX activity, so interrupt generation is seperate and additional to the SPI registers.